# How to get my hashmap to return multiple values to one key in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am at my wit's end. I've been learning Python from LearningPythontheHardWay, I was learning well until exercise 39 with the dictionary module hashmap. 
I can get it to work with just key, value pairs. I want this module to allow me to work with multiple values to each key. There was another question on here like this but it wasn't answered completely, or I did not understand the answer. I want to learn Python, but this is really restricting me from progressing and I need help.

```
def get(aMap, key, default=None):
    """Gets the value in a bucket for the given key, or the default."""

    bucket = get_bucket(aMap, key)
    i, k, v = get_slot(aMap, key, default=default)

    for k in enumerate(bucket):
        while v:
            return v #returns the value of the key!!!
```

This get function from the module does not work. I can get Python to list the entire dictionary with multiple key values using list function, so I know the values are in there through my set function:

```
def set(aMap, key, value):
    """Sets the key to the value, replacing any existing value."""

    bucket = get_bucket(aMap, key)
    i, k, v = get_slot(aMap, key)

    bucket.append((key, value))
```

I know I'm supposed to get a value list in there and then loop through the list if the key should contain more than one value.

I am having a hard time putting this in code language. The bucket contains the list for the tuple (k,v) pairs and the k should contain a list of v.

So far I can only get one value to appear and it stops. Why does the while loop stop?

Thank you.

EDIT: For more clarity, I want to return multiple values if I input a single key that has more than one value.

```
cities = hashmap.new()
hashmap.set(cities, 'MH', 'Mumbai')
hashmap.set(cities, 'MH', 'Pune')
hashmap.set(cities, 'MH', 'Augu')
print ("%s" % hashmap.get(cities, 'MH'))
```

This should return all those values out.

Comment: I think it might be easier for people to answer your question if you could pare it down a little bit.  What is your expected result, and what is the result you're getting?  Also, naming a function `set` might be not be a good idea, because it already refers to the function that creates a set variable.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the "**return**"  keyword always terminates the function(callee) and jump to caller, that's why you can not "**return** multiple value by using return keyword multiple times".
The workaround are

1. return a **list** or **tuple**(as suggested by @terry-jan-reedy)
2. implement as [Iterators & Generators](http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html)

Comment: The standard idiom is to return multiple valies as a tuple, such as in `return a, 2, 'third'`.

Answer (score 0):

A hashmap is a hash by key (means efficient research algorithm) not by value ... 
If I understand correctly you seems to fear that the value may be a complex type.

The simplest dictionary is

```
{"key1":"Value1", "key2":"Value2"}
```

Where you can also have:

```
{"key1": [1,2,3,"hello"], "key2": A_class_instance, "key3": range(500) }
```

then value should be as complex as you want ...

now if you want to build a hash map of values (for filtering for instance)
you may glance at the following code:

```
Mydic = {}
for k,v in My_huge_key_value_table_of_couples:
  try:
     Mydic[k].append(v)
  except KeyError:
     Mydic[k] = [v]
```

to build a hash map with multiple value in each values

Now To access it with default value

just

```
def get (amap, key, default=None):
   try:             return amap[key]
   except KeyError: return default
```

to strictly answer the question

Edit to match your hashmap edit.. 
If you write hashmap.new() ... you had imported a hashmap module, yours ?
I suppose there hashmap is a dictionary

cities = {} # create the dictionary

```
def set (amap, key, value):
   try: amap[key].append(value)          #append the element if key already exists
   except KeyError: amap[key] = [value]  # Init the first element
set(cities, , 'MH', 'Mumbai')
set(cities, 'MH', 'Pune')
set(cities, 'MH', 'Augu')
def get (amap, key, default=None):
  try:   return ','.join(amap[key])   # You must return a string not a list
  except KeyError: return default     # in case of no key
print get(cities, 'MH')
```

Supposing hashmap exists ;-) as a tuple of unfixed limit tuples.
in the form:
((k,v),(k1,v1,v2), ... )
Your code is a little bit hard to follow.
Keep in mind also that a tuple is static and stand for static data.
Manipulating tuple as you want should be tricky

```
def get_h(h, k):
  # like that ? 
  def get_bucket(h,k):  
      # supposition get_bucket return the tuple (key, value1, value2) as a list: [ value1, value2 ] ? 
      # even if your line bucket.append((key, value)) in the set function is a non sens !
      #it will produce [ value1, value2, (key, value)] result
     for f in h:
        if f[0] == k: return list(f[1:])
  bucket = get_bucket(aMap, key)
```

but be carefull at this level you cannot do

```
print ("%s" % get_h(cities, 'MH'))
      #       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--------> is a list not a string 
print ("%s" % ','.join(get_(cities, 'MH')))    # is correct
```

Tips: You should use the IDLE .. to test things .. it is often very usefull

Comment: What I would want is exactly as the "key1" there IF and only if the key has multiple values. Is it not possible for some code to loop through value after making the value part of the tuples as a list?

Comment: yes you can ... when  you do value = amap[key], you add a for on value if it is a list (or a tuple)

Comment: Hashmap was just another term zed shaw used for dictionary data structure so he didn't declare any variable as a dictionary like you did there with "Mydic"

Comment: It doesn't seem to work...I tried declaring value = amap[key] but it says list indices must be integers and not string after I execute the test program

Comment: if you type print type(amap) it must return <type 'dict'>

Comment: But aMap isn't exactly a dictionary though, from what I understood. He was going with making a list containing tuples to make it look like a dictionary where every key has its value pair.

Comment: ok in this case I failed, maybe hashmap a python 3 specificity

Comment: It has to be really simple... I mean this dictionary module is basically a list of tuples : ((key,value),(key,value)) <--- aMap ,
What I want is : ((Key,value1,value2),(key,value)) and be able to call all values if I input the first key.

Answer (score 0):

I think your first question is how to store multiple values for each key. We can try storing the values as a list. I think the changes you need to make are mainly to the functions set().

```
def set(aMap, key, value):
    """Sets the key to the value, multiple values for each key"""
    #i, k, v = get_slot(aMap, key)
    bucket = get_bucket(aMap, key)
    i, k, vlist = get_slot(aMap, key) 
    if i >= 0:
        # if key exists, append value
        vlist.append(value)
    else:
        # the key does not exist, append a key and list. The list stores the values
        bucket.append((key, [value]))
```

The `[value]` refers to the list.

To get the values, we can change the get function to:

```
def get(aMap, key, default=None):
    """Gets the values in a bucket for the given key, or the default."""
    i, k, vlist = get_slot(aMap, key, default=default)
    return vlist
```